# How to stop a Dataframe subset from "remembering" old values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Sorry for the weird phrasing, but I didn't know how to better describe it. I will be translating my problem to US terms to ease understanding. My problem is, I have a national database with States and Districts and I need to work only with Districts from Florida, so I do this:

```
df_fl=df.loc[df.state=='florida'].copy()
```

After some transformations I want to take mean values of every district from Florida, so I do this:

```
df_final=df_fl.groupby(['district']).mean()
```

But this brings a dataframe with every district in the database. All rows from districts that are not in Florida are filled with nans. I suppose there's an easy solution to this, but I haven't been able to find it. It's kinda counter intuitive that it works like that, too.

So, can you help me fix this?

Thanks in advance,

Edit:
my data looked like this:

```
District   state      Salary
   1        Florida    1000
   1        Florida    2000
   2        Florida    2000
   2        Florida    3000
   3        California 3000
```

df_fl, then, looks like this:

```
District   state      Salary
   1        Florida    1000
   1        Florida    2000
   2        Florida    2000
   2        Florida    3000
```

And after applying

```
df_final=df_fl.groupby(['district']).mean()
```

I expected to get this:

```
District   Salary
   1        1500
   2        2500
```

But I'm getting this:

```
District   Salary
   1        1500
   2        2500
   3         nan
```

Obviously a very simplified version, but the core remains.

Comment: Can you plz share some data to reproduce/trace the output? I'm new to data frames but I was wondering if you could try `df_final =df.loc[df.state=='florida'].groupby(['district']).mean()`

Comment: Cannot reproduce when I recreate a dataframe as you describe (`pandas 0.21.1`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As piRSquared already explained this only happens with categorical data. Starting from 0.23.0 `groupby` has a new "observed" argument which toggles this behavior. MCVE taken from piRSquared:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    State=list('CCCCFFFF'),
    District=list('WXWXYYZZ'),
    Value=range(1, 9)
))
>>> df.assign(
    District=pd.Categorical(df.District)
).query('State == "F"').groupby('District').Value.mean()
District
W    NaN
X    NaN
Y    5.5
Z    7.5
Name: Value, dtype: float64
>>> df.assign(
    District=pd.Categorical(df.District)
).query('State == "F"').groupby('District', observed=True).Value.mean()
District
Y    5.5
Z    7.5
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Very nice.  I didn't know about that option (now I do).  @JuanC I don't mind at all if this is the accepted answer.  It uses the api as intended.  To be more explicit, I prefer this solution over mine.

Comment: If that's the case, I will mark this one as the answer, but both were very enlightening. Thanks to both !

Answer (score 5):

It is because your `'District'` column is a categorical type.

### MCVE

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    State=list('CCCCFFFF'),
    District=list('WXWXYYZZ'),
    Value=range(1, 9)
))
```

#### Without categorical

```
df.query('State == "F"').groupby('District').Value.mean()

District
Y    5.5
Z    7.5
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

#### With categorical

```
df.assign(
    District=pd.Categorical(df.District)
).query('State == "F"').groupby('District').Value.mean()

District
W    NaN
X    NaN
Y    5.5
Z    7.5
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

---

### Solution

Many ways to do this.  One way that preserves the categorical typing is to use the method, `remove_unused_categories`

```
df = df.assign(District=df.District.cat.remove_unused_categories())
```

Comment: Exactly the answer. It wasn't as simple as I expected, but it's nice to know about the option to remove unused categories! Thanks a lot